# LinkedIn og:image tag does not work when I add link to my personal profile but does work when I make posts

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api, meta-tags

I've tried refreshing the LinkedIn cache using the LinkedIn post inspector and it's updated to the correct image for LinkedIn posts only. The image used when I add the link to my profile is incorrect. I've attempted to refresh the cache three times over the past 6 weeks but no luck. Does anyone know how I can correct this?

The photo I want displayed is - http://www.sleepmap.co.uk/assets/cover-6e0fd100baa9a43ef559aecb6acd6e9665b5f8c40144a9af5f6a8cccc0218a88.png

The photo actually displayed is - https://sleepmap.co.uk/assets/philips-8a84892c8351523c740f6fd4588ec0a73d217a3579d58ba6a54a5a5882e0d1ed.png

The website is a single page site at www.sleepmap.co.uk

All of my meta tags can be seen below. I don't know if it is relevant but I'm using Ruby on Rails and I can share more code if needed.

```
<!-- Facebook Open Graph data -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Sleep Map - Make your home help you sleep">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.sleepmap.co.uk/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.sleepmap.co.uk/assets/cover-6e0fd100baa9a43ef559aecb6acd6e9665b5f8c40144a9af5f6a8cccc0218a88.png">
<meta property="og:description" content="SleepMap uses smart technology in your home to help you sleep longer and better. Over time we learn what the perfect set-up is for you by tracking how well you sleep and making small adjustments to things like your lights and temperature.">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Sleep Map - Make your home help you sleep">

<!-- Twitter Card data -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@SleepMap">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Sleep Map - Make your home help you sleep">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="SleepMap uses smart technology in your home to help you sleep longer and better. Over time we learn what the perfect set-up is for you by tracking how well you sleep and making small adjustments to things like your lights and temperature.">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SleepMap">
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.sleepmap.co.uk/assets/cover-6e0fd100baa9a43ef559aecb6acd6e9665b5f8c40144a9af5f6a8cccc0218a88.png">
```

Code for the image actually displayed is below:

```
 <div class="card-invisble col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <%= image_tag "philips.png", class: 'align-middle company-logo' %>
    <p class="align-middle"><b>Lights</b></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, none of the code provided has the URL for the image you are getting, so the problem can't be in that little snippet of code you provided.

- This one:
  https://sleepmap.co.uk/assets/philips-8a84892c8351523c740f6fd4588ec0a73d217a3579d58ba6a54a5a5882e0d1ed.png

I suggest you add more code.

Comment: That image is used once and I'll add the code to the original post now. It is a single-page website and the site can be found at www.sleepmap.co.uk

Comment: Ok, now where is the code where you call the image you mentioned you wanted ? As far as I can see on the comment you just added, you are calling philips.png" so what do you expect getting?

Comment: By using the image tag, rails looks inside the app/assets/images folder for an image with the name philips.png

Comment: The image displays perfectly on the website and all of the images use image_tags

Comment: Yes, i know that. But you said you wanted this: http://www.sleepmap.co.uk/assets/cover-6e0fd100baa9a43ef559aecb6acd6e9665b5f8c40144a9af5f6a8cccc0218a88.png // But the code you provided is for fetching of this:  https://sleepmap.co.uk/assets/philips-8a84892c8351523c740f6fd4588ec0a73d217a3579d58ba6a54a5a5882e0d1ed.png. See where I'm getting at?

Comment: As for the cache, you can use private browsing, or use Firefox Developer Edition. It sorts that out for you. And if you want to use Chrome without private mode, you can use DevTools -> Application -> Clear Cache

Comment: Those links were generated by the LinkedIn post inspector. Both of the images are stored in the assets/images folder and are called cover.png and philips.png respectively. Using chrome in private browsing did not help. If I'm not mistaken, the cache refresh in the LinkedIn post inspector is for the LinkedIn scraper and their server. It is not for my local and so clearing the cache on my computer shouldn't make a difference.